# Laravel same route for different middlewares

Tags: laravel, routes, middleware, roles

I have problem with routes and middlewares. I have 5 middleware roles. Administravimas, birstonas_biblioteka, druskininkai_biblioteka, birstonas_registratura,druskininkai_registratura.

The problem is that some same routes can access several roles. But when i declare same route to different middlewares only one of them can access and when i use or in routes with multiple middlewares then every roles can access route.

Middlewares code Administravimas:

```
class Administravimas
{
    /**
     * Handle an incoming request.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @param  \Closure  $next
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function handle($request, Closure $next)
    {
        $userRoles = Auth::user()->roles()->pluck('pavadinimas');
        //$collection = DB::table('roles_users')->select('*')->get
        //dd($userRoles);
        if(!$userRoles->contains('Administravimas'))
        {
            return redirect('/prieiga-nesuteikta');
        }
        return $next($request);
    }
}
```

Middlewares code birstonas_registratura

```
public function handle($request, Closure $next)
{
    $userRoles = Auth::user()->roles()->pluck('pavadinimas');
    //$collection = DB::table('roles_users')->select('*')->get
    //dd($userRoles);
    if(!$userRoles->contains('Birštonas registratūra'))
    {
        return redirect('/prieiga-nesuteikta');
    }
    return $next($request);
}
```

Web routes :

```
Route::group(['middleware' => 'Administravimas' OR 'birstonas_registratura'], function () {
    Route::get('books', 'BookController@index')->name('books');
    Route::post('books', 'BookController@add')->name('book.add');
    
});
```

Kernel:

```
'Administravimas' => \App\Http\Middleware\Administravimas::class,
    'birstonas_biblioteka' => \App\Http\Middleware\BirstonasBiblioteka::class,
    'druskininkai_biblioteka' => \App\Http\Middleware\DruskininkaiBiblioteka::class,
    'birstonas_registratura' => \App\Http\Middleware\BirstonasRegistratura::class,
```

So how i declarate same route only for some groups not for all.

Comment: Or i need to use different routes for the same function?

Comment: you make a milddleware that you can pass multiple parameters to for the different roles you want to allow, instead of a multiple middleware that only check single roles

Comment: can you give some example trying to do that but no luck

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can pass parameters to middleware, so you can make a middleware that you can pass the name of all the roles you want to allow:

```
public function handle($request, $next, ...$roles)
{
    $userRoles = Auth::user()->roles()->pluck('pavadinimas');

    foreach ($roles as $role) {
        if ($userRoles->contains($role)) {
            // they have the current iterated role
            // let them pass through
            return $next($request);
        }
    }

    // they don't have any of these roles
    // redirect away
}
```

Then assigning your middleware:

```
`rolescheck:Admin,student`
```

Using what you currently have as a base example.

Comment: Done this but works only for first parameter for second get access denied

Comment: it will check all the roles you pass, it doesn't stop unless it finds one you have or you don't have them at all